# How to know path of calling shell directory and use it in my python executable

Tags: python, ubuntu, path, executable

Basically, I want to call a python program from anywhere using shell so I added a shebang and copied it to `/usr/local/bin` with executable permission. The python program takes a command line argument which is the relative path of an input file. 

I am stuck here, I have no idea what to do so that I can obtain the absolute path of the shell. I am assuming once I get the absolute path somehow, I can use `sys.argv[1]` to get the entered relative path of the file(which I will append to the absolute path of shell working directory) but please do correct me it won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Print Working Directory via `os.environ['PWD']`. Content of `your_script.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.5

import os
print(os.environ['PWD'])
```

Usage:

```
sanyash@sanyash-ub16:/etc/nginx$ your_script.py 
/etc/nginx
sanyash@sanyash-ub16:/etc/nginx$
```